# Convert Twig array to a PHP array

Tags: multidimensional-array, twig

Using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) I'm able to get the contents of a twig file which contains just one multidimensional array:

**Twig:**

```
{% set settings = {
  theme : '#91141b',
  transforms : {
    thumb  : { mode:'crop', width:300,  height:300, quality:80, position:'center-center'},
    small  : { mode:'fit', width:100,  height:100, quality:70, position:'center-center'},
    header : { mode:'fit', height:800, quality:80, position:'center-center'},
    mobile : { mode:'crop', width:640,  height:1136, quality:60, position:'center-center'}
  },
  globals : {
    telephone : '123456678',
    address : '42 Wallaby Way, Sydney'
  },
  social : {
    facebook : 'http://www.facebook.com',
    twitter  : 'http://www.twitter.com',
    linkedin : 'http://www.linkedin.com',
    youtube  : 'http://www.youtube.com'
  }
} %}
```

In PHP, I now have this string to play with:

```
{% set settings = { theme : '#91141b', transforms : { thumb : { mode:'crop', width:300, height:300, quality:80, position:'center-center'}, small : { mode:'fit', width:100, height:100, quality:70, position:'center-center'}, header : { mode:'fit', height:800, quality:80, position:'center-center'}, mobile : { mode:'crop', width:640, height:1136, quality:60, position:'center-center'} }, globals : { telephone : '123456678', address : '42 Wallaby Way, Sydney' }, social : { facebook : 'http://www.facebook.com', twitter : 'http://www.twitter.com', linkedin : 'http://www.linkedin.com', youtube : 'http://www.youtube.com' } } %}
```

Is there a way to turn this into a usable PHP multidimensional array? Like this:

**PHP:**

```
$settings = array(
  'theme' => '#91141b',
  'transforms' => [
    'thumb'  => [ 'mode'=>'crop', 'width'=>300, 'height'=>300, 'quality'=>80, 'position'=>'center-center'],
    'small'  => [ 'mode'=>'fit',  'width'=>100, 'height'=>100, 'quality'=>70, 'position'=>'center-center'],
    'header' => [ 'mode'=>'fit',  'height'=>800,'quality'=>80, 'position'=>'center-center'],
    'mobile' => [ 'mode'=>'crop', 'width'=>640, 'height'=>1136,'quality'=>60, 'position'=>'center-center']
  ],
  'globals' => [
    'telephone' => '123456678',
    'address' => '42 Wallaby Way, Sydney'
  ],
  'social' => [
    'facebook' => 'http://www.facebook.com',
    'twitter'  => 'http://www.twitter.com',
    'linkedin' => 'http://www.linkedin.com',
    'youtube'  => 'http://www.youtube.com'
  ]
);
```

I wonder if there is a parser function I'm unaware of.

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: why you want to extract the twig array into PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I sort of figured it out.

In the twig file, render out the settings variable with a [json_encode](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html) filter:

```
{{ settings|json_encode|raw }}
```

Then in your PHP plugin you can render in the twig file and use PHP's [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$file = '_includes/settings';

$settings = json_decode(craft()->templates->render($file), true);
```